# customising a progress-bar with different images

Tags: android, ios, progress-bar, titanium, custom-component

I've seen in the progress bar api, there is a property for 'backgroundImage'. Is there a way in titanium to create a custom progress bar? If I have two images? Or has anyone heard of a module which could let me do such a thing?